# Hooks to run after a core upgrade?

Tags: plugins, hooks, upgrade

Are there any hooks for running plugin code after a core upgrade?

Specifically, I'm running into issues that a users wp-admin column choice in the 'Screen Options' are [modified](http://jaxov.com/2010/06/wordpress-3-0-publish-update-button-missing/) after an upgrade - I believe if they choose "auto". After doing an svn sw I lost my "publish" box from the post/pages page. This is causing some major issues in my wp-admin skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the filter [`update_feedback`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/update_feedback), he works after the update and you can use for all stuff after an update.

An example plugin can you find in [this trunk](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/unwanted-plugins-remover/trunk/unwanted-plugins-remover.php).

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: Which link, all linked strings are really fine, Currently.

Comment: the update_feedback link is not working.

Comment: Works for me on each test, goal is http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/update_feedback

Comment: It only works for me when I use USA Proxy

Comment: I'm in Germany, works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_core_updated_successfully` action hook to run your plugin code after the WordPress core upgrade.

The hook passes the current WordPress Version as parameter.

```
add_action( '_core_updated_successfully','your_function');
function your_function(){
    //code to be executed after WordPress Core Update
}
```